# Hide 0 value in SUM calculations

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple sheet with additions, it looks like this:

[image]

B column is for the sum of the values on the right, and if there is no value on a row, it shows 0, but let's say I want it to say 'None' instead, or just be empty if there is no value to sum. B row functions are currently like this:

> =SUM(C7:M7)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a similar approach for replacing both blanks and text.

Similar to [@doubleunary's second approach](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172651/), I would trigger an error, but I would use that same aporoach in both cases and simply change the result based on preferred error handing (blank vs. string).

### Multi-Row Formula

The following formula in `B2` will calculate the SUM for all rows in the range C2:M20

##### Return Empty Values

```
=BYROW(C2:M20, LAMBDA(row,
    IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(row)))))
```

##### Return A String

```
=BYROW(C2:M20, LAMBDA(row,
    IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(row)),"text")))
```

#### Return String but Skip Blank Rows

```
=BYROW(C2:M1000, LAMBDA(row,
   IF(LEN(JOIN(,row)), 
    IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(row)),"Text"),)))
```

- If returning blanks instead of text, the additional approach has no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

To display a text string when the sum is zero, use this pattern:

```
=if(sum(C7:M7), sum(C7:M7), "(none)")
```

To display a blank when the sum is zero, use `iferror()`:

```
=iferror(1 / sum(C7:M7) ^ -1)
```

See [iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply to hide the **`0`** value, rather than replace it, you can apply a custom number format to the cells.

1. Navigate to **Custom number format** using any of:

   1. **`Format menu > Number > Custom number format`**
   2. **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>**
   3. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> ***
      *<sub><sup>If Compatible Spreadsheet KB Shortcuts are enabled.</sup></sub>*
      <sub>[image]</sub>
2. Custom number formats follow the following pattern:
   **`positive;negative;zero;text`** 
   <sub>[image]</sub>
   Therefore, any of the following formats would hide zero values:
3. **`0;-0;;@`** 
   <sub>[image]</sub>
4. **`0;-0;`**
   <sub>[image]</sub>